# How we can zip sum panda series of lists?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

for the below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': "A", 'inv' : [1,2,3,4,5]},
                   {'id': "A", 'inv' : [1,2,3,4,5]},
                   {'id': "B", 'inv' : [1,2,3,4,5]},
                   {'id': "B", 'inv' : [1,2,3,4,5]}])
```

how we can get zip sum for each ID:

the result like:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'id': "A", 'inv' : [2,4,3,8,10]},
              {'id': "B", 'inv' : [2,4,3,8,10]}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your data size, you may get more performance with [awkward](https://awkward-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html):

```py
import awkward as ak
import awkward_pandas as akpd
(df
.astype({'inv':'awkward'})
.groupby('id')
.inv
.apply(lambda x: ak.sum(x,axis=0))
)
id
A    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
B    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
Name: inv, dtype: object
```

Comment: Its pretty awkward that I didn't hear about the awkward yet.. Good answer:)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
out = df.groupby("id")["inv"].apply(lambda x: [sum(t) for t in zip(*x)]).reset_index()

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
  id               inv
0  A  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
1  B  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with lambda function and `map` with `sum` and `zip`:

```
out = df.groupby("id", as_index=False)["inv"].agg(lambda x: list(map(sum, zip(*x))))
print(out)
  id               inv
0  A  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
1  B  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

If possible different length of lists is possible use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'id': "A", 'inv' : [1,2,3,4,5]},
                   {'id': "A", 'inv' : [1,2,3,4,5]},
                   {'id': "B", 'inv' : [1,2,3,4,5]},
                   {'id': "B", 'inv' : [1,2,3]}])
print (df)
  id              inv
0  A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1  A  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
2  B  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3  B        [1, 2, 3]

from  itertools import zip_longest

out = (df.groupby("id", as_index=False)["inv"]
         .agg(lambda x: list(map(sum, zip_longest(*x, fillvalue=0)))))
print(out)
  id               inv
0  A  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
1  B   [2, 4, 6, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

use `np.array` or `pd.DataFrame` as shown below:

```
(df.groupby('id', as_index = False)['inv']
   .agg(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(list(x)).sum(0)))

  id               inv
0  A  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
1  B  [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
import pandas as pd

series1 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])
series2 = pd.Series([4, 5, 6])

zipped_series = zip(series1, series2)
summed_series = [sum(pair) for pair in zipped_series]

print(summed_series)
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.